# Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_t)_{t\leq1}$ and $(Y_t)_{t\leq1}$ be such that $0\leq X_t\leq Y_t$ w.p. $1$ for each $t$, and assume the following:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{t\to0}\mathbb{E}[Y_t]=K
\end{equation*}
Does that allow me to conclude:

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}\mathbb{E}[Y_t] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{t\to0}Y_t]$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{t\to0}X_t]$

If not, what additional conditions would be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P}) = ([0, 1], \mathcal{B}, \mathrm{Leb})$ and

$$ X_{t}(\omega) = Y_{t}(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1/t & \omega \leq t \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}. $$

Then

$$\Bbb{E} X_{t} = \Bbb{E} Y_t = 1 \neq 0 = \Bbb{E}\lim_{t \to 0} Y_{t} = \Bbb{E}\lim_{t \to 0} X_{t}. $$

The existence of the *dominating function* is crucial for ensuring the interchange of the integral and the limit.